# nodejs - Async generator/iterator with or without awaiting long operation

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand which setup is the best for doing the following operations:

1. Read line by line a CSV file
2. Use the row data as input of a complex function that at the end outputs a file (one file for each row)
3. When the entire process is finished I need to zip all the files generated during step 2

**My goal**: fast and scalable solution able to handle huge files

I've implemented step 2 using two approaches and I'd like to know what is the best and why (or if there are other better ways)

#### Step 1

This is simple and I rely on [CSV Parser - async iterator API](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/async_iterator/):

```js
async function* loadCsvFile(filepath, params = {}) {
  try {
    const parameters = {
      ...csvParametersDefault,
      ...params,
    };
    const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
    const csvParser = parse(parameters);
    const parser = inputStream.pipe(csvParser)
    for await (const line of parser) {
      yield line;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error while reading csv file: " + err.message);
  }
}
```

#### Step 2

##### Option 1

Await the long operation `handleCsvLine` for each line:

```js
// step 1
const csvIterator = loadCsvFile(filePath, options);
// step 2
let counter = 0;
for await (const row of csvIterator) {
  await handleCvsLine(
    row,
  );
  counter++;
  if (counter % 50 === 0) {
    logger.debug(`Processed label ${counter}`);
  }
}
// step 3
zipFolder(folderPath);
```

**Pro**

- nice to see the files being generated one after the other
- since it wait for the operation to end I can show the progress nicely

**Cons**

- it waits for each operation, can I be faster?

##### Option 2

Push the long operation `handleCsvLine` in an array and then after the loop do `Promise.all`:

```js
// step 1
const csvIterator = loadCsvFile(filePath, options);
// step 2
let counter = 0;
const promises = [];
for await (const row of csvIterator) {
  promises.push(handleCvsLine(row));
  counter++;
  if (counter % 50 === 0) {
    logger.debug(`Processed label ${counter}`);
  }
}

await Promise.all(promises);
// step 3
zipFolder(folderPath);
```

**Pro**

- I do not wait, so it should be faster, isn't it?

**Cons**

- since it does not wait, the for loop is very fast but then there is a long wait at the end (aka, bad progress experience)

#### Step 3

A simple step in which I use the [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) library to create a zip of the folder in which I saved the files from step 2:

```js
function zipFolder(folderPath, globPath, outputFolder, outputName, logger) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // create a file to stream archive data to.
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(outputFolder, outputName));
    const archive = archiver("zip", {
      zlib: { level: 9 }, // Sets the compression level.
    });

    archive.glob(globPath, { cwd: folderPath });

    // good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
    archive.on("warning", function (err) {
      if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
        logger.warning(err);
      } else {
        logger.error(err);
        reject(err);
      }
    });

    // good practice to catch this error explicitly
    archive.on("error", function (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      reject(err);
    });

    // pipe archive data to the file
    archive.pipe(stream);
    // listen for all archive data to be written
    // 'close' event is fired only when a file descriptor is involved
    stream.on("close", function () {
      resolve();
    });
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using `await` does not make operations faster. It will not wait for the response and will move to the next operation. It will keep adding operations to the event queue, with or without `await`.

You should use `child_process` instead to mock parallel processing. Node js is not multithreaded but you can achieve it using `child_process`, which runs on CPU cores. This way, you can generate multiple files at a time based on number of CPU cores available in the system.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Do you mean using `child_process` inside the for loop? One for each long operation? If yes then I need to handle a "pool" of processes in order to avoid spawning too many of them (the CSV file contains thousands or even millions of rows)

Comment: Probably, the easiest way for using efficiently `child_process` is to delegate their management to a library like [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)

Comment: Ideally, you should take the repeating operation to `child_process`. In your case, it is generating a CSV with numerous records. And then at the end, you can zip those together. And yes, delegation to external package would be a good idea.